# WCF serialization and performance

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I've noticed that if I convert an object to a byte array like this:

```
MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(memorystream, objectToSerialize);
byte[] toSend = memorystream.ToArray();
```

and then send that byte array through WCF (`WsHttpBinding` / `NetTcpBinding`), and then serialize it on the client also with `BinaryFormatter`, it takes much less time than just sending object through WCF.

How can I enable WCF to convert any object that sent to it to a byte array and only after that send it to the client?

Comment: As i understand, wcf converts object with DataContractSerizalizer to WCFMessage and then converts to binary format by Formatter(binary in this article). What I'm looking for is to convert object before it comes through DCS, because DCS takes a lot of time to serialize the object.

Comment: Note that when you serialize this way you gain performance but lose the ability to deserialize in other platforms or even in other versions of your object (if a field is added, the serialization will fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own serialization/deserialization, take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434665/WCF-Serialization-A-Case-Study)

Or you can use [Proto-buf .Net port](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/TestWcfDto/IService1.cs) serializer instead.

The [performance comparisons](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) show that Protocol Buffers outperform the built-in serializers in terms of both size and serialization/deserialization speed.

Please take a look at this [sample project](https://github.com/maxbrodin/Protobuf-wcf-sample/) on github